# rational function with absolute values

Tags: functions, absolute-value, rational-functions

How can i write a rational function with absolute values as a piecewise function, 
for example  $$f(x)= \frac{|x+1|}{|x+2|}$$

Comment: You just have to form the cases $x>-1,-1\ge x>-2,-2>x$, like always.

Comment: thank you !! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

$$\frac{|x+1|}{|x+2|}=\left| \frac{x+1}{x+2}\right|$$

Hence, you just have to figure out when does $\frac{x+1}{x+2}\ge 0.$

Comment: thanks a lot :D